# The costs of Obfuscation

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-20th-anniversary

Obfuscate is clearly a strong discipline. Like, at level 2 it allows a Nosferatu to at least get places, and a 3 totally negates their Appearance 0 trait by appearing as whoever they want - as long as they are a good manipulator and actor. It gets even better at 4, when he becomes unnoticeable by the vast majority and at 5 it's a whole group that goes invisible or runs around as whoever the Vampire wants. There are even relatively few drawbacks...

Did I overread costs associated with the abilities but for the one case that Mask of 1000 Faces costs 1 blood point per appearance you need to *boost*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No.

Doesn't look like you've missed anything. Obfuscate doesn't cost much as far as blood goes. Its two weaknesses are that it doesn't (ordinarily) shield you from technological measures like cameras and motion sensors and that the counterdiscipline of Auspex is equally cheap and more common.

Answer (score 3):

### No.

Just like [the answer by Jadasc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/193243).

However, I want to add that there is one rather large restriction for the invisibility application of Obfuscate - a vampire using it should not draw attention to themselves or they risk being revealed. So, a vampire can be invisible in a room but if the doors and windows are closed, they cannot leave without risking exposure. A curtain at your door might be enough to alert you that an invisible vampire was sneaking through it.

So, Obfuscate is not all powerful. Kindred who know the Discipline are not guaranteed to never be seen.

With that said, it is nothing to scoff at, either. The Discipline *is* very strong. It does allow for getting into places where few, if none, others can. Learning information thought hidden. And otherwise subvert security.

This is in-line with most Discipline powers. A single dot in Potence can *double* the strength of a vampire. OK, only if they originally started with Strength of 1 but it is still a lot more than they would get as a human. Getting 2 dots in Potence makes the vampire obviously supernaturally strong. An apparent weakling of Strength 1 can lift and throw things that you cannot guess by their physique. And a strong-ish one (Strength 3) can now compete with the world's strongest men.

Many Disciplines allow for truly phenomenal feats. Presence can manipulate even Elders. Dominate can command mortals to even be unwitting pawns. And Celerity...it is straight up broken, always has been. Getting extra actions in combat is mechanically superior to most tactics. It is even more broken than Obtenebration and Vicissitude which started off as NPC only powers and thus were not originally meant to be on-par with player powers.

This power of Disciplines is supported by the description of what Disciplines are in the beginning of the chapter (page 127)

> Disciplines are supernatural powers granted by the Embrace, which vampires cultivate to bring to bear against their foes and prey. These powers separate the Damned from mortals, providing an incomparable mystical edge over those who would stand against them.

One sourcebook (might have been *Clanbook: Ventrue*) talked about how even a fledgeling Ventrue has enough powers to single-handedly start a nuclear war with Dominate and Presence by infiltrating a nuclear base and just commanding soldiers to launch a nuke.